# Using Reduce to solve trig equations. Error: unable to decide whether numeric quantity .. is zero

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages, trigonometry

I'm trying to find solutions to a fairly simple pair of simultaneous equations in variables $\phi_1, \phi_2$ using Reduce.

```
θ = Pi/8; (* e.g. 3.14 also doesn't work *)
points = Solve[
   Reduce[{Sin[ϕ1] + 0.1 Sin[θ + ϕ1 + ϕ2] == 
       0 && ϕ1 > -Pi && ϕ1 <= π && 
      0.1 Sin[ϕ2] + 0.1 Sin[θ + ϕ1 + ϕ2] == 
       0 && ϕ2 > -Pi && ϕ2 <= π} , {ϕ1, ϕ2}]]
```

However, Reduce seems to run into trouble when an external parameter $\theta$ in the equations is set to some decimal expansion, say 3.14 as opposed to $\pi$, and also when set to numbers around $\pi/8$. Reduce returns the empty list, while we know there are solutions. There are errors `Reduce::ratnz` and `Reduce::ztest1`:

[image]

[image: le]

PS: I will be scanning through many values of $\theta$ and also coefficients of the Sine functions so I need a fail proof way of finding all solutions in order to automate it.

Answer (score 4):

A lot of trigonometric equation solving problems seem to work better if one uses the Weierstrass substitution.

```
With[{θ = π/8, φ1 = 2 ArcTan[u1], φ2 = 2 ArcTan[u2]}, 
     eqs = RootReduce[GroebnerBasis[{Sin[φ1] + Sin[θ + φ1 + φ2]/10 == 0, 
                                     Sin[φ2]/10 + Sin[θ + φ1 + φ2]/10 == 0} // TrigExpand,
                                    {u1, u2}]]];

{2 ArcTan[u1], 2 ArcTan[u2]} /. NSolve[Thread[eqs == 0], {u1, u2}, Reals]
   {{-3.0444244788667807, -1.8157299550057586},
    {3.0425062641101692, 1.4239899806853435},
    {0.020515491894360593, 2.934985366795896},
    {-0.018597277132295528, -0.1870509022832146}}
```

You can replace `NSolve[]` with `Solve[]` if you want to see exact solutions, but that might take you a while.

Comment: If you omit `RootReduce`, `Solve` is relatively quick, about 1 sec.

Comment: Indeed, I just tried it out now, but the result will now need to be massaged with `(Full)Simplify[]`. Eep.

Comment: It seems to fail if I change the factors of 1/10 to 0.1?

Comment: @Rudyard, yes, inexact numbers like `0.1` often do not play nice here, so you either use fractions and exact numbers, or use something like `Rationalize[]`.

Comment: It seems to run into trouble for this example:

`θ = Pi/6; With[{φ1 = 2 ArcTan[u1], φ2 = 2 ArcTan[u2]}, eqs = GroebnerBasis[{Sin[φ1] + 97/100 Sin[θ + φ1 + φ2] == 0, 97/100 Sin[φ2] + 97/100 Sin[θ + φ1 + φ2] == 0} // TrigExpand, {u1, u2}]]; points = {2 ArcTan[u1], 2 ArcTan[u2]} /. NSolve[Thread[eqs == 0], {u1, u2}, Reals]`

Comment: In general it doesn't seem to be able to always pick out all solutions to the equations

Comment: @Rudyard, it looks like you found a case where preprocessing the set of equations to a Gröbner basis does not help. In that specific case, you can do this instead: `With[{θ = π/6, φ1 = 2 ArcTan[u1], φ2 = 2 ArcTan[u2]}, eqs = Numerator[Simplify[{Sin[φ1] + 97/100 Sin[θ + φ1 + φ2], 97/100 Sin[φ2] + 97/100 Sin[θ + φ1 + φ2]} // TrigExpand]]]; {2 ArcTan[u1], 2 ArcTan[u2]} /. NSolve[Thread[eqs == 0], {u1, u2}, Reals]`

Comment: Thank you! Is there a general condition a priori that would tell me which version to use?

Comment: @Rudyard, the latter one is more general, but if it is taking too long to evaluate, that is where one might consider preprocessing with `GroebnerBasis[]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
θ = Pi/8;(*e.g.3.14 also doesn't work*)
points = 
Solve[{Sin[ϕ1] + 1/10 Sin[θ + ϕ1 + ϕ2] == 
   0 && ϕ1 > -Pi && ϕ1 <= π && 
  1/10 Sin[ϕ2] + 1/10 Sin[θ + ϕ1 + ϕ2] == 
   0 && ϕ2 > -Pi && ϕ2 <= π}, {ϕ1, ϕ2}] //
  N // Values
```

is this what you want?

> {{-3.04442, -1.81573}, {0.0205155, 2.93499}, {3.04251, 1.42399}, {-0.0185973, -0.187051}}

Comment: That's much better thanks! It still seems to have problems in some cases, say, $\theta = 3.001$ ?

Comment: @Rudyard well, since it seems doesn't matter, you can just ignore the warning. (It happens because you use a *Floating point number* instead of *exact number* in `Solve`.) .If you don't want to see it, use `//Quiet`.

Comment: Oh I don't mind errors; I meant it's not actually able to solve it. Another example, try:

```
Solve[{Sin[\[Phi]1] + 0.3 Sin[ \[Phi]1 + \[Phi]2] == 
   0 && \[Phi]1 > -Pi && \[Phi]1 <= \[Pi] && 
  0.1 Sin[\[Phi]2] + 0.3 Sin[ \[Phi]1 + \[Phi]2] == 
   0 && \[Phi]2 > -Pi && \[Phi]2 <= \[Pi]}, {\[Phi]1, \[Phi]2}] //
  N // Values
```

Comment: @Rudyard  first , in comment , type \\ to type \ , single \ will disappear. second, you could use `3/10` instead of `0.3` . third, `Solve` is unable to solve this equation directly. fourth , use `\`  \`` to contain code.

Comment: Thanks. Another example with coefficients rationalised below. You're saying Solve simply can't handle these?
`Solve[{Sin[\\[Phi]1] + 1/100 Sin[\[Phi]1 + \\[Phi]2] == 
      0 && \\[Phi]1 > -Pi && \\[Phi]1 <= Pi && 
     40/100 Sin[\\[Phi]2] + 1/100 Sin[\\[Phi]1 + \\[Phi]2] == 
      0. && \\[Phi]2 > -Pi && \\[Phi]2 <= Pi}, {\\[Phi]1, \\[Phi]2}] // 
  N // Values `

Comment: @Rudyard, you forgot to convert one of the `0.` into `0` for the second equation.

Comment: fixed this but still doesn't work